# Listagg result binding variable

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I hava a this query `select LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) as "id_no"  from student_all` .

It is working but I want to use result in a variable so I wrote this query like this

```
select LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) into a_value  from student_all
```

but it is not working. My error is missing keyword.

Also I wanted to write a function for the testing but same error.I did not created function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
 FUNCTION list_id(
   periods     IN NUMBER,
   p_student_id      IN  NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
    str VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
    ORDER BY  id DESC)
    INTO str
   FROM student_all
   WHERE status = 'IN' AND id = p_student_id  FETCH FIRST periods ROWS ONLY 
   RETURN str;
 END;
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: put a semi-colon after `ROWS ONLY` clause(*I assume your DB version is 12c+,isn't it?*). Btw, length of str(200) might be short, might be replaced with 32767.

Comment: Which Oracle version do you use?

Comment: I use 19c edition

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I tried it but not working

Comment: There's no problem with [your function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f62381a9412fb51bb51573bb90b14e99) except for the one I already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

- Semicolon is missing at the end of the `SELECT` statement
- `FETCH` clause is not used properly.

I think you are looking for the code to fetch only a few rows and then do `LISTAGG`. You can use the following code.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY  id DESC)
  INTO str
FROM (SELECT ID
        FROM student_all
       WHERE status = 'IN' 
         AND id = p_student_id  
      ORDER BY ID
      FETCH FIRST periods ROWS ONLY);
```

Comment: It gives missing keyword. I think I cannot use into clause with listagg.

Comment: You can definitely use the `INTO` with `LISTAGG` but make sure that you put this query in your function as it will throw the error if executed independently.